# get the text value in the dropdown with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get the selected text of the option.

```
<select class="float-left groupNames" name="Group">
       <option value="preview[object Object]0">test</option>
        <option value="preview[object Object]1">test1</option>
        <option value="preview[object Object]2">test2</option>
    </select>
```

I tried `$(".groupNames option:selected").text();`
but its not the right value. so I am getting `testtest2` if I am selecting the third option.

Comment: seems to work, it selects the selected option (without setting a selected, selected is the first option), can you show us what you have exactly?

Comment: *"but its not the right value"* And how should *we* know what the right value is supposed to be?

Comment: @FelixKling It seems he/she wants to get the `value` but the above snippet returns the `textContent`.

Comment: @Vohuman: Probably. But there are other possibilities as well. Just saying. It's hard to help without knowing what the desired outcome is.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, exactly. Also the value attributes look suspicious!

Comment: Regarding your update: It seems like you have multiple `.groupNames` elements. That's the only explanation for getting this output. You have to select the one you want to get the option text from. Please provide a **complete** example that reproduces the issue. You are not new to Stack Overflow, you should know how this works!

Comment: you got it right. I have 2 groupNames element.how to select the one I want. this is the second one in the HTML.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 2):

`$(".groupNames").val()` is all you need.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wz1938h3/)**

However if you have multiple .groupNames elements, you'll need to be more specific with the selector.

`$(".groupNames option:selected").text();` as you probably saw, will get the selected option's text, not the select's value.

Comment: sorrrryyy I want to get the text only.

Answer (score 0):

hi please add an id to easily access the select here is an tested fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/elviz/259m3qkb/1/

```
    $("#newSkill").change(function(){
         var kamote = document.getElementById("newSkill").options[document.getElementById('newSkill').selectedIndex].text;
       alert(kamote);
     });
```